# Consuming jsx from configuration in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a platform that will consume jsx files from an independent configuration system in react.

The use case here is that we need runtime CRUD on react components and other js files, without touching/deploying the react instance in any way. Does react provide a way to do this?

I know this can be done by avoiding the jsx to js transpilation and directly relying on the `createElement` method and modding the watch-asset to look up the data source instead.

Comment: I'm really curious as to why you need to do this, it seems super awkward. And if you're doing CRUD operations on the react files then you ARE "touching" the react instance. What are the constraints that led to this?

Comment: The react instance I am talking about powers the platform, wherein I can describe a UI using JSX. Since its a platform I can't have it deployed every time a UI element needs modification.